# using jQuery how to continue through a set of animations after custom function is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of animations (fadeIn/Out...).  in the middle of running these, I need to run a custom function.  Once the function has run, I want to continue to the next item in the series.

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
context.delay(300).fadeIn(500, function(){
    // Step 4
    context_item(900, function(){
        // Step 5
        tag.delay(300).fadeIn(400).shuffleLetters({callback:function(){
```

the first part is delaying then fadeIn. On complete, I run context_item() which is a function:

```
function context_item(duration){
    var msg = $('#intro-context span'); 
    var delay = duration;

    msg.each(function(index){
        var item = $(this);
        item.show();

        if(index == 3) {
            item.shuffleLetters(400);
        } else{
            item.shuffleLetters({callback:function(){
                item.delay(delay).fadeOut(300);
            }});
        }
    });
}
```

Once context_item has run its course, I want to step back into Step 5 from above.  I am trying to treat my function like many of the jQuery effects like fadeIn(time, function(){});

stuck.

many thanks for the help

-- EDIT

The problem is that once the context_item function has run through its .each, it is not moving on to step 5.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: I edited the question to better detail the problem

Comment: So you mean it's not running its callback?

Comment: should context_item(900, function((){ DO MORE STUFF}); work? I am a novice at js/jquery so I am trying to understand.  I would have thought I had to tell it to DO MORE STUFF at the end of the function creation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to create a function with a callback.

This is how your `context_item()` function should look in this case :

```
function context_item(duration, f){
    //your code
    if (typeof f == "function") f(); else alert('A function must be passed for f');
}
```

Comment: That is indeed exactly what I was trying to do.  to clarify for myself: by running f(); you are running the function() call right before step 5...  thhanks

Comment: @TJSherrill you are running the `Step 5` after `context_item` is done executing